# Error in eval(predvars, data, env), stepwise linear regression in a loop

Tags: r, package, linear-regression

I would like to implement the stepwise linear regression in a function. Example of my code is given bellow.

```
test_function <- function(formula, dataset, k, repeats) {

  # k is a number of folds used for cross-validation (CV)
  # repeats represents the number of repeats of CV

  for (m in 1:repeats){

    # randomly shuffle dataset
    dataset <- dataset[sample(nrow(dataset)), ]

    #Create k equally size folds
    folds <- cut(seq(1, nrow(dataset)), breaks = k, labels = FALSE)

  for (j in 1:k){

    #Segement my data by fold using the which() function
    testIndexes <- which(folds == j, arr.ind = TRUE)
    test <- dataset[testIndexes, ]
    train <- dataset[-testIndexes, ]

    MLR <- stats::step(lm(formula, data = train), direction = "both", trace = TRUE)
    test_predicted <- predict(MLR, test)

      }
  }
}

# Example
# install.packages("dendroTools") # to get data used in the example below
library(dendroTools)
data("example_dataset_1") # load the data used in the example bellow

test_function(formula = MVA~., dataset = example_dataset_1, k = 10, repeats = 2)
```

And it works perfectly. But I would like to implement this function in my R package. And when I run RCMD check for this example. I get the following error:

```
... 166 lines ...
- T_aug_sep  1    0.2973  8.0723 -92.866
<none>                    7.7750 -92.817
- T_APR      1    4.2533 12.0283 -72.127

Step:  AIC=-92.87
MVA ~ T_APR

Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : 
  invalid 'envir' argument of type 'closure'
Calls: test_function ... eval -> eval -> <Anonymous> -> model.frame.default -> eval
Execution halted
```

It looks like, the problem occurs, when there is a non-significant variable.

Comment: This will require you outputting more rows of the error and code to clearly pinpoint the error.

Comment: Those are all lines of RCMD check that I can see. It should be clear, where is the problem: 
When there is only one significant variable (in my example: T_APR), predict function returns the error. I suspect, the problem is because in the test data, there are also insignificant variables. However, I can't understand why error is returned by RCMD check, but when I run it as a function in R, everything is OK.

Comment: where is the sample data?

Comment: library(dendroTools); 
data("example_dataset_1") # load the data used in the example bellow